# Check module compatibility with different Perl versions

Tags: perl, perl-module

Is there a command line switch or any other easy way that I can check the compatibility of my module with different versions of perl? I understand that if I put `use 5.6.1;` at the top of a script, the script will have any features later than 5.6.1 disabled. But if I have a module which uses several other modules and so on, I need a quicker way to check what minimum version of Perl to require in my Makefile.PL or Build.PL.

Comment: Upload to [PAUSE](http://pause.perl.org/); [CPAN Testers Matrix](http://matrix.cpantesters.org) runs just about about everything on every Perl version on every OS.

Comment: "I understand that if I put use 5.6.1; at the top of a script, the script will have any features later than 5.6.1 disabled". If you omit `use 5.6.1`, the script will stall have later features disabled.

Comment: @Flimm Yeah, that's probably a typo but I can't remember what I was saying. Should be "enabled"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run your module against [`Perl::MinimumVersion`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl%3a%3aMinimumVersion).

Comment: MUCH better than running through multiple perls (though that has its own merits)

Answer (score 5):

`use v5.6.1` and similar will primarily raise a compile-time error if the version of Perl in use is older than that specified. In addition, the corresponding feature bundle is enabled, and if the version is v5.11 or higher,  the `strict` pragma is enabled as well.

`use v5.6.1` will not make Perl v5.8 behave like v5.6.1, and there is no way of achieving this. Even in later versions it is only features  that can be controlled using the `feature` pragma that are adjusted to a given version.

To test your module you will have to install each different version of Perl and test it separately

Comment: The documentation of the feature pragma states, that `use` of `v5.10` or later automatically includes the corresponding feature bundle.

Answer (score 2):

You can just install different versions of perl and test against those. I install them by hand in different locations but if you want to automate that, use perlbrew.

There might be scripts or strategies that try to find the minimum version of perl needed, but everything i tried several years ago to obtain and aggregate the minimum perl version i found clunky and unreliable. Which of course doesn't mean, that it doesn't exist or can't be done, but just that i couldn't find it.

Comment: I usually don't use Windows, but when i do, i use Strawberry Perl.

Comment: It is useful to have a Linux test rig in a virtual machine. VirtualBox will give you a VM for free.

Comment: I second using perlbrew. It's great for running multiple version of Perl on one machine. See http://perlbrew.pl/